# как правильно организовать бинарное дерево?

Tags: c++

дали задание: сделать дерево отношений. Как я понял с объяснения однокурсника, это бинарное дерево, про что угодно(семейное и т.д.). 
само бинарное дерево я +- сделал(семейное дерево). Но возникает вопрос, что делать если у моего дедушки не 2 а 3 ребенка? куда вписать 3-го?

Comment: нужно более четко сформулированное задание, если в генеалогическое дерево нужно вместить то о чем вы написали, то бинарного дерева здесь явно недостаточно. Если же вам нужен вариант как на картинке, то вполне можно обойтись и им: https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-zen_doc/230574/pub_5b33ef8edf4db600a9ee7303_5b34f3ff25800d00a82cfb24/scale_1200

Comment: ну...нужно сделать дерево так, чтоб потом указав на какой-то елемент дерева программа вывела всех его предков

Comment: Я бы послал такого однокурсника и сделал n-арное дерево

Comment: Вам нужно выводить потомков или предков? Если предков, то учитывая что партеногенезом мы не размножаемся(пока) - то вывод предков любого человека будет как бинарное дерево. Но если выводить потомков - то это n-нарное дерево. Смотря с какого конца смотреть. А вообще, то лучше уточнить задание у препода, чем посылать однокурсника. Вы вполне можете оказаться не правы за неимением достаточного количества информации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В бинарное дерево можно поместить только предков, т.к. у человека строго два родителя.
А если нужно в генеалогическом дереве иметь и других родственников, то получится дерево, у которого в узлах, кроме родителей, есть дополнительное поле - список братьев и сестёр. Этого будет достаточно.